# mysql query data not displaying properly

Tags: mysql

I have a site where the client stores event info into a database... really simple.

the issue is when I want to get the data out. I can currently do so by selecting all data and ordering it by the month asending....

What I need is for it to display all the info as it does now, except it needs to display this info by listing all data for the current month first then the next month and so on. I dont care if I have to just simply list the info in proper ascending monthly oder and just make it scroll to the current months first event....

Currently I have the following for my db.

```
ID, year, month, day, event_loc, event_address, event_link, event_time, event_name
```

you can see it in action here:

http://www.michael-eubanks.com/events.php

Comment: Can you post your current database query?

Comment: kindly show your working  db query  or sample code you are working

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a SQL like this:

```
select * from <tablename> order by year desc, month desc, day desc
```

It will order the data first by year, then by month, then by day, all in descending order, and hence you should see the most recent event first, and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

if I am correct, the thing you want is grouping(aggrigation), so all you need is group by:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable GROUP BY month ORDER BY month DESC;
```

and I used descending, to display the current month first.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly and you want to select only events starting from the first day of the current month then you can do it like this

```
SELECT ID, year, month, day, event_loc, event_address, event_link, event_time, event_name
  FROM events
 WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', year, month, day), '%Y-%c-%e') >= DATE_FORMAT((CURDATE()), '%Y-%m-01')
 ORDER BY year, month, day
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50c32/2)** demo

---

Now, to be able to normally query your data using indices and range searches I'd suggest to change your table's schema to utilize `datetime` (for `event_date` column) and `time` (for `event_duration`) data types. Proposed schema might look like this

```
CREATE TABLE events
(`ID` int, 
 `event_date`     datetime, 
 `event_loc`      varchar(256), 
 `event_address`  varchar(256), 
 `event_link`     varchar(256), 
 `event_duration` time, 
 `event_name`     varchar(256)
);
```

Then the query would look like

```
SELECT ID, DATE(event_date) event_date, 
       event_loc, 
       event_address, 
       event_link, 
       CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(event_date, '%l:%i%p - '), 
              DATE_FORMAT(ADDTIME(event_date, event_duration), '%l:%i%p')) event_timee, 
       event_name
  FROM events
 WHERE event_date >= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-01')
 ORDER BY event_date
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9eed3/1)** demo

Comment: @user2813652 Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?